# User Defaults migration from Obj C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I am working on an `Update` for my `OS X` app which was initially written in `Obj-C`.
The update has been re written in `Swift`

---

I am facing a strange problem of User Defaults handling.(Since User preferences must not be changed in update)

All the native type (like `Bool, String`) user preferences are working fine, but the the Class which was `NSCoding` compliant is not able to `deserialse / Unarchive`. It is giving an error :

```
Error :[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (KSPerson) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked
```

I made following try outs, but still not able to figure out the solution

1. Initially I thought that it was due to different class names(in
   `Swift` its `Person` instead of `KSPerson`). But changing the class name (back to `KSPerson`) did not solve the problem
2. Inorder to make class more `Objective C` like I also tried prepending the class with `@objc`

---

Here is the code

```
let UD = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

func serialize() {
    // Info: personList: [KSPerson]
    let encodedObject: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(personList)
    UD.setObject(encodedObject, forKey: "key1")
    print("Serialization complete")
}

func deserialise() {
    let encodedObject: NSData = UD.objectForKey("key1") as! NSData
    let personList: [KSUrlObject] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedObject) as! [KSPerson]

    for person in personList {
        print(person)
    }
```

---

Note:
I created a `duplicate copy` of `Objective C` code, and it deserialised ( what was serialised by original copy) perfectly.
To my surprise. when I rename the class `KSPerson` to `JSPerson` in `duplicate copy` it gave me the exact same error as seen above

So one thing is clear. You need to have same class name to Unarchive `NSCoding` compliant `objects`. But this is clearly not sufficient for `Swift`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Swift classes include their module name. Objective-C classes do not. So when you unarchive the Objective-C class "KSPerson", Swift looks through all its classes and finds "mygreatapp.KSPerson" and concludes they don't match.

You need to tell the unarchiver how to map the archived names to your module's class names. You can do this centrally using `setClass(_:forClassName:)`:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(KSPerson.self, forClassName: "KSPerson")
```

This is a global registration that applies to all unarchivers that don't override it. You of course can register multiple names for the same class for unarchiving purposes. For example:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(KSPerson.self, forClassName: "KSPerson")
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(KSPerson.self, forClassName: "mygreatapp.Person")
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(KSPerson.self, forClassName: "TheOldPersonClassName")
```

When you write Swift archives, by default it will include the module name. This means that if you ever change module names (or archive in one module and unarchive in another), you won't be able to unarchive the data. There are some benefits to that (it can protect against accidentally unarchiving as the wrong type), but in many cases you may not want this. If not, you can override it by registering the mapping in the other direction:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("KSPerson", forClass:KSPerson.self)
```

This only impacts classes archived after the registration. It won't modify existing archives.

This still is pretty fragile. `unarchiveObjectWithData:` raises an ObjC exception when it has a problem, which Swift can't catch. You're going to crash on bad data. You can avoid that using `-decodeObjectForKey` rather than `+unarchiveObjectWithData`:

```
let encodedObject: NSData = UD.objectForKey("key1") as? NSData ?? NSData()
let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: encodedObject)
let personList : [KSPerson] = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as? [KSPerson] ?? []
```

This returns `[]` if there's a problem rather than crashing. It still respects the global classname registrations.

Comment: Thanks. While searching for answer I found this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11452. It states that adding @objc(name) declaration, would make the class available to Obj-C w/o namespacing. What are the use cases of this vs NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass

Comment: The poster noted that he had not tried that technique and didn't know whether it would actually work. I agree with the poster that you'd expect it to work, but it doesn't in my tests.

Comment: Using @objc still didn't work. Using `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(KSPerson.self, forClassName: "KSPerson")` was perfect.

Comment: Using @objc + NSCoding + setClass fixed it for me. Also using decodeObjectForKey didn't protect nor from crash "because no class named was found" nor from crash "unexpected non-objectlike class"